# Python date.today() not working with pandas pdr.get_data_yahoo)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am trying to use Yahoo's pandas stock reader library. I currently have the following code:

```
today=str(date.today())
print(today)
print(type(today))
start_date= '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2021-06-14'

stockData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock,start=start_date,end=today)
```

I get '2021-14-06' and <class 'str'> for the output of

```
print(today)
print(type(today))
```

For some reason, in the get_data_yahoo() function when I use end=end_date it works, but end=today stops at 6-11-2021. The two are exactly the same so I'm very confused why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: maybe try `today=str(date.today().date())`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: it's because the stock market is closed on weekends so there was no data for those dates :(